# React : useState send empty value the first time but not the second time to my child component...?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-props

I want to pass `props` to my child component `PaperGovernment` . my props contains an Object. My problem is when I try to `console.log()` the props that I will send to my child component, I see two array. The first is empty and the second is filled of my data as you can see below :

[image]

Could you help my to solve this problem please ?

```
const GovernmentId = (props) => {
    let { id } = useParams();

    const { arrayMinistriesInfo } = props;

    const [governmentList, setGovernmentList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/GovernmentCreate/byId/${id}`)
            .then((res) => {

                const resData = res.data;

                arrayMinistriesInfo.map((valueMinitries) => {
           
                        Object.keys(resData).map((i) => {
                        
                            if (i === valueMinitries.dataBase) {
                                resData[i][0].icon = valueMinitries.icon
                                resData[i][0].nameMinistry = valueMinitries.nameMinistry

                            }
                        });
                    
                });

                setGovernmentList(resData);
       

            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, []);
    return (
        <Box>
            Bonjour
            {console.log(governmentList)}
        </Box>
            //<PaperGovernment governmentList={governmentList}/>        
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the expected behavior.

```
const [governmentList, setGovernmentList] = useState([]);
```

Here you set governmentList as an empty Array, so the initial value is an empty array.

If you want to give the array to the children component once you have fetched your data, you can do it like this:

```
{governmentList.length && <PaperGovernment governmentList={governmentList}/>}
```

This way, you only give the array to the child component if it is not empty.
If you want, you can also have a more complex logic, for instance by storing in a local state a boolean that tells when you fetched the array (in the useEffect, at the end, it would look like this:

```
setGovernmentList(resData);
setFetchIsDone(true);
```

And then with the same logic, you can give the fetched array to the child component:

```
{fetchIsDone && <PaperGovernment governmentList={governmentList}/>}
```

Note that with my first way to proceed, you don't give the array to the child component if it is an emty array, so if you want to be able to still give it to the children, even if it is an empty array, you should rather consider the second way to proceed

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly my array doesn't pass to my component. Certainly because of my array still empty the first time...?

Comment: It is no problem if it is array the first time, because your component will be rerendered once you fetched the array, so it will not be empty in the end. What is not working in your case? You could maybe try to provide a reproducible example, in a codesandbox ?

Comment: I was creating exemple on codesandbox and I find my issu. Your solution was find, but my `governmentId` wasn't an array but an object *(my mistake to didn't realize it)*. So I did `setGovernmentList([resData]);` and that work.

Comment: I'm glad I could hel anyway haha
Actually, trying to reproduce your issue in a codesanbox helps a lot, because you realize what you are doing wrong when trying to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
 <Box>
            Bonjour
           {governmentList?.length > 0 && console.log(governmentList)}
        </Box>
```

Comment: the question mark is not required, since it should not be undefined

Comment: Hi @TheTisiboth ,ok ```{governmentList.length > 0 && console.log(governmentList)}```